# slf4j - Using log4j appender Issue

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have spent many days trying to solve following logging problem with slf4j:

```
Class Sample {
....
private static final org.slf4j.Logger A = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class);
```

//A = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FileLogger") makes no difference

```
private static final Logger B = Logger.getLogger("FileLogger");
...
}
```

***Slf4j logger A always makes entries to stdout, never into the log file.***

***Log4j logger B works as expected, making all entries in the log file.***

Is there a way/configuration Slf4j logger can use the same appender log4j uses? I can't upgrade to logback. Has anyone come across this issue?

I have made sure all the required slf4j libraries with same version are in the project path:

- org.slf4j.slf4j-api
- org.slf4j.slf4j-log4j12
- apache-log4j-extras : version - 1.2.17

log4j xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
          <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
 <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <param name="file" value="sample.log"/>
        <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <rollingPolicy class="rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="sample.%i.log.gz"/>
            <param name="MaxIndex" value="5"/>
            <param name="MinIndex" value="1"/>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100"/>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMMdd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %c %t" />
        </layout>
            </appender>

            <logger name="FileLogger">
                <level value="INFO" />
                <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
            </logger>

            <root>
                <level value="INFO" />
            </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Don't use log4j-over-slf4j! It is meant for people using log4j API who want their log4j calls to go into slf4j.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sample.class).getClass().getName());`. This helps you to idenfity, of what type the SLF4J logger is. Sometimes, logback or java.util.logging sneak into SLF4J without being obvious.

Comment: Also please provide a **real** and working code sample. When I try to run your code it complains first of all that the log4j.xml is incomplete (missing the root "configuration" tag), then that there is no `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` class ([true](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html)), next that there is no `datePattern` parameter on RollingFileAppender, and finally that there is no appender for the "Sample" logger (also true).

Comment: In summary, once I fix all these issues, it behaves exactly as I expect: B goes to the file and A goes *nowhere* (with an error message about lack of appenders). If I change A to use your commented-out line, then both loggers go to my file. The summary of the summary is: provide a real working code sample, because I can't replicate based on your info.

Comment: @dcsohl - thanks for your help. I removed the log4j-over-slf4j, added the missing log4j configuration and included apache-log4j-extras. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Still not a real working code sample. It's giving me parsing exceptions on the log4j.xml, based around the line `<rollingPolicy class="rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">`... there probably shouldn't be two `class` attributes and you should probably close the quotes on the first of them. Ignoring this, when I rectify this it still behaves as I expect--see my last comment for what it does. Hasn't changed.